# How to find the control which causes LostMouseCapture event fire in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I handled an event "LostMouseCapture" on my wpf text box . Now I need to implement functionality that if this event got fire because of click of one specific button then I want to do something and if this event got fire because of some thing else then i want to do some other thing.

I am blank how to achieve this functionality

```
 private void txtEcode_LostMouseCapture(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
 {

     //if the event is fired because of click of "btnEcode" then do this
      {
        MCondsViewModel.McondsNo = MCondsViewModel.EcodeValueOnMouseFocus;
      }
      else
      {
                 //do this
      }
  }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to directly handle the Button's Click event?

Comment: Thank you @Clemens for your reply I bound to use this event only and its bit difficult for me to explain the reason here as it need lots of explanation